# Error Gestor Modulos Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, modulos, prestashop1.7

Cuando entro a prestashop salta ese error, y no puede entrar en la opcion de gestor de modulos porque al cargar esa página se queda en blanco, a las demas páginas si que puedo entrar.
Gracias, un saludo.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]